# How to read line by line multiple files

Tags: command-line, scripts

let's say I have an undertermined number of files

in `/mnt/traitement` and I want to read line by line every file in this folder how do I do it, I know that to read files line by line you need to do this code

```bsh
while read line
do
   #stuff
done < file
```

but I don't know how to target multiple files.

Comment: Do you want to read the files sequentially, one complete file after another; or in parallel, the first line of each file, then the second and so on? And what do you want to do with each line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be sufficient to wrap the while loop into a for loop:

```bsh
for i in file1 file2 file3; do
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
         #stuff
    done < "$i"
 done
```

If you care only about the text itself, you can just `cat file1 file2 file3 | while IFS= read -r line`, but beware of non-newline terminated files, as `cat` will splice last item of that file with first line of new one.

Also, since you mentioned particular directory, you can use glob with the for loop as in `for i in /mnt/traitement/*`. Like so

```bsh
for i in  /mnt/traitement/*   ; do
    if ! [ -f "$i" ]; then
        continue
    fi
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
         #stuff
    done < "$i"
 done
```

Comment: note however that the glob by default does not match hidden files, set `shopt -s dotglob` in case any of the files begins with a dot.

Comment: Noted but im trying your second answer and it throws me an error : 
cannot open /mnt/traitement/depot/*

Comment: @PostMaloneM3m3r Ah, that's because the glob includes directories as well. You'd need to add check for whether what's in `$i` variable is a regular file.

Comment: i don't know what you mean

Comment: See the edited answer

Comment: I know I said file1 file2 file3 file4 but, can you make this answer as if It for were for an undertemined number of files?

Comment: @PostMaloneM3m3r Well  that's exactly the purpose of the `*` glob. It expands to everything in the directory you mentioned.  Among other things, I'd suggest you edit the requirements into the question. The question clarity is directly proportional to answers quality :)

Comment: Ok i'll edit my question

Comment: I missed a bit in the last example. Edited

Comment: I marked your answer as correct but,

it still throws me errors so I don't know how to fix them.

Comment: Which errors specifically ? Post to paste.ubuntu.com and provide link

Comment: https://imgur.com/sQdxKTM

Comment: Remove the backticks from `/mnt/traitement/*`. Backticks are form of command substitution, which means when `/mnt/traitement/*` expands to `/mnt/traitement/file1  /mnt/traitement/file2 /mnt/traitement/file3` it will treat the first one as command. In this case we don't want that. We only want `/mnt/traitement/*` to be treated as list, and that's it, no backticks

Comment: ok noted, I tried that because it showed nothing but maybe it's because I have nothing on my folder, anyway thanks!